# From Vonage video API to Vonage Business Communications app

Tags: vonage, vbc

Goodmorning,
I need to build a simple web app in which an user push a button, after pressing it a video call starts and I am trying to find the easyest solution.
In few minutes I was able to embed a video call on a test web page using Vonage Video API.
I am wondering if using Vonage video API is it possible to "call" from the web browser interface to the Vonage Business Communications app for Android of iPhone.
So: I click the button on the webpage, a video call starts and the phone with Vonage Business Communications installed rings.

Is it possible? If so I'll learn how to do that.

Many thanks in advance, Guido.

Comment: Have you seen Vonage Video Express? https://tokbox.com/developer/video-express/

It sounds like it is a fit for your use case. Calling a VBC account might be possible but will likely require a lot of work and custom code on your part. Happy to look into this for you if Video Express does not help

Comment: Many thanks, I'll give it a try ;-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @abdulajet mentioned, Video Express might be a good way to go - however, you won't be able to interface with VBC.

Might be worth also looking at our much simpler Meetings APIs: https://developer.vonage.com/meetings/overview